# Creating a new column using string match and based on if-else condition

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a data frame with a column 'url_text' containing text output from an OCR. I am trying to create a new column 'blocked' where the rows equal 1 if a condition is met and 0 otherwise.

```
df[df['url_text'].str.contains('blocked you')] # detect all rows in 'url_text' column 
# that contain 'blocked you'. Code works.
```

I have tried to insert the above code in the following function. However, when I apply the function to my data frame I get the following error:

```
def f(row):
    if row['url_text'] == df[df['url_text'].str.contains('blocked you')]:
        val = 1
    else:
        val = 0
    return val
```

```
df['blocked'] = df.apply(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/marcoliedecke/Desktop/Who_Blocks_Who?/Code/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 8740, in apply
    return op.apply()
  File "/Users/marcoliedecke/Desktop/Who_Blocks_Who?/Code/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 688, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/Users/marcoliedecke/Desktop/Who_Blocks_Who?/Code/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 812, in apply_standard
    results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
  File "/Users/marcoliedecke/Desktop/Who_Blocks_Who?/Code/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 828, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)
  File "<input>", line 3, in f
  File "/Users/marcoliedecke/Desktop/Who_Blocks_Who?/Code/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 942, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "/Users/marcoliedecke/Desktop/Who_Blocks_Who?/Code/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1051, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "/Users/marcoliedecke/Desktop/Who_Blocks_Who?/Code/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py", line 388, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'url_text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root problem here is that your code compares a single string (`row['url_text']`) to a dataframe (`df[df...]`)

Instead of referencing `df` inside your function, just use methods that are defined on the row itself. You can also implement this as a lambda function to be closer to the [canonical examples](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

```
df['blocked'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: 1 if 'blocked you' in row['url_text'] else 0,
    axis=1
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Sarah. Your comment makes sense. However, when executing your code I get the error message ```SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument```.

Comment: @MarcoLiedecke My bad. I swapped the order of the inputs.  I'll update my answer.  Please try it again with the updated order.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time @Sarah. Your updated code gives me the following error:  `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: @MarcoLiedecke That's what I get for giving suggestions without testing them.  Try it one more time, please